# storyboard usage for ipad development giving lots of problems

Tags: ipad, storyboard, constraints, ios10

I'm developing an iPad portrait-only app and i'm having trouble with the inferred view.  This will be an enterprise level app so i'm wondering if i should be working only with freeform view and just put in the size of the an actual iPad.  would this be considered best practice?

below is one such issue, i put in the right constraints for this for an ipad but it's giving me trouble because of the inferred view.

[image]

another issue is that i'll be inputting lots of text fields and so that many won't be able to fit in an inferred view.

Answer (score 0):

you can select view as on the lower left

[image]